# Enums and binary or operator (MISRA C++ 2008, 4-5-2)

Tags: c++, enums, misra

MISRA C++ 2008, 4-5-2 states: Expressions with type enum shall not be used as operands to built-in operators other than the subscript operator [ ], the assignment operator =, the equality operators == and !=, **the unary & operator**, and the relational operators <, <=, >, >=.

If one can use & why it is not allowed to use binary | with enums?

Comment: Why do you want to do operands on an enumeration?  If you need to rely on the underlying values, then you shouldn't really be using enum. Use const or #define.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in another answer, you are mixing up *binary* & with *unary* &.

The reason why you can't use binary | and other bitwise operators on enums is that enumerated types (variables of enum type) have implementation-defined size and signedness. And enumeration constants (the values in the enumeration list) always have type `signed int`.

In either case, using any form of bitwise operations on signed numbers is always problematic: you can get unexpected results or invoke poorly-defined behavior. This is the main problem that the rule seeks to prevent.

MISRA also banned regular arithmetic with the same rationale: don't do arithmetic on a type which you don't know the size and signedness of. Not as likely to cause bugs, but I guess there's a place for it if you do weird stuff like `enum { X=30000 }; ... X + X`. Is this well-defined, or an implicit promotion to `int`, or undefined because of integer overflow? It could be either of these cases and it isn't necessarily tied to the CPU data size.

Comment: _"enumeration constants (the values in the enumeration list) always have type signed int."_ Do they though?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I think it's C++11 7.2/5 "Each enumeration defines a type that is different from all other types. Each enumeration also has an
underlying type. The underlying type can be explicitly specified using enum-base; if not explicitly specified, the underlying type of a scoped enumeration type is int.". In C11 it is 6.7.2.2/1 "The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type int and may appear wherever such are permitted."

Comment: _"of a scoped enumeration type"_ Other enums exist; plus http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#5 doesn't so constrain the types of the values themselves (nor, ultimately, of the underlying type)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Actually C++03 says something different yet and that's the relevant version for MISRA-C++.

Comment: It certainly doesn't talk about scoped enums ;)

Comment: Thanks! If I overload binary operators & and | where I convert enums to int and then do binary operations on them, should these be exempted?

Comment: @user28458 Unusual operator overloading is highly questionable in systems with MISRA requirements, so probably not. I don't know MISRA-C++ all that well, you need to look up other rules regarding which operators you are allowed to overload, if any.

Answer (score 4):

You're making a false comparison.

Unary `&` is the "address-of" operator, and has no relationship to the *binary* `&` "and" operator.

The MISRA rules have prohibited all bitwise operations on enumerations, while continuing to permit taking the address of an object of such a type.